# mysql_query() expects parameter 1 to be string, resource given

Tags: php, html, mysql

1. ```
   $abc = mysql_fetch_array($result);
     if (!$result)
        die("Error: Data not found..");        

   $name=$abc['name'] ;
   $email= $abc['email'] ;                 


   $sql = "UPDATE example SET name ='$name', email ='$email' WHERE id = '$id'";
       if(mysql_query($con, $sql)) //Error
           Echo "Record Update successfully";
       else
           Echo "ERROR: could not able to execute $sql".mysql_error($con); 

   mysql_close($con);
   ```

Comment: mysql_query() expects parameter 1 to be string, resource given //this is error

Comment: `mysql_query($sql,$con)`

Comment: 1 error solve thnks, & another error = could not able to execute UPDATE example SET name ='', email ='' WHERE id = '19'Table 'test.example' doesn't exist

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please see [ask] and [The perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your code in this way :

```
$sql = "UPDATE example SET name = $name,email = $email WHERE id = $id";
mysql_query($sql,$con);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to swap the $con and $que paramters in your mysql_query function.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Answer (score 0):

you must replace $sql with $con

```
if(mysql_query($sql, $con))
       {
        Echo "Record Update successfully";
       } 
       else
       {
        Echo "ERROR: could not able to execute $sql".mysql_error($con);
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

you may use mysqli instead, which is the new version of mysql with more security features, but you have to unit all the code to use either mysql or mysqli

```
mysqli_query($connection,$query);
```

OR

```
mysql_query($query,$connection);
```

whenever you use the mysqli, you should set parameter 1 to be the connection resource